# slides.js slides_control has 0 height and slide show not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I am trying to implement a slide show with slides.js on the home page of a new shoify site,

http://naturallog.myshopify.com/

as you can see the images are loading to the page, but div#slides_control has zero height and the slide show isn't working. I don't see any js errors in firebug and jquery and slides.js are loading to the page as well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Figured it out, the version of jquery included with the theme I was using was too old the sliders.js plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM jquery version needed to be updated for the plugin